# how to give option to a user to update its own info in Identity Server

Tags: c#, api, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have derived Identity User as

```
    public class MyAppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public MyAppUser () : base() { }
        public MyAppUser (string userName) : base(userName) { }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string CurrentAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

I have added all these properties values in claims also so that we can send these values to user to see the details.

```
await UsersRepository.AddClaimAsync(appuser, new Claim("firstName", "MyName"));
await UsersRepository.AddClaimAsync(appuser, new Claim("lastName", "MyLastName"));
await UsersRepository.AddClaimAsync(appuser, new Claim("currentAddress", "MyAddress"));
```

I have two issues here

**Issue 1:-** The values are repeated at two places.

- with the MyAppUser
- with the Claims

**Question:-** Is it a correct way? if not, what is the best to implement it?

**Issue 2:-** I want to give an option to user to update its own information like CurrentAddress or FirstName or
LastName.

**Question:-**

One way to solve above problem is give admin api endpoint access to all users. But is it correct way? What is the best to implement this in IdentityServer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using IdentityServer4, I would create a "profile" scope by defining an identity resource. https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html#identity-resources

```cs
public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
{
    return new List<IdentityResource>
    {
        new IdentityResource(
            name: "profile",
            userClaims: new[] { "name", "email", "website" },
            displayName: "Your profile data")
    };
}
```

From there, you can look at implementing the `IProfileService` interface in order to access a separate database or API that manages your users' profile information.

Profile Service Docs : https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html#refprofileservice

You can set up a separate User Profile or User Information service where your users can go to update their information and what not. This way they are not directly modifying data within the bounds of the actual authentication service. You can remove unnecessary claims from the authentication token and only supply them as part of your "profile" scope. That would cut down on the redundant claims that you mentioned. Doing so also gives you more room to add whatever user profile info you might want (phone number, email, etc.).

Comment: User Profile or User Information service -> this service will be in Identity Service Admin API ?

Comment: @DJ There's multiple ways you could implement it based on your specific application/use-case. You could indeed extend the identity server API by adding your own controller(s) and endpoints. I don't know how your overall architecture is laid out, so I can't recommend a specific approach. I imagine you have separate applications or APIs which you are protecting with ID4? If so, you could add the functionality there which keeps it separate from the main authentication server. Depends what makes most sense for your use case. The simplest is probably to just extend the identity server API.